# Add author's name to view

Tags: 7, views

Is there some simple way I can add the author's name as a field to be displayed in my view?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In view add a relationship Content: Author

[image]

Then choose User: Name under fields,

[image]

this will display author name

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much, that worked really well!

Answer (score 1):

**Beyond a Views only Solution**

I would recommend using the module [Realname](https://drupal.org/project/realname), as it provides a solution that will work for views, but will also alter the display name on the author archive pages, and the author's display name on a node created by them:

1. Download and enable [Realname](https://drupal.org/project/realname) module
2. Create a new field on users (admin/config/people/accounts/fields) I called it "Display name" (field_display_name)
3. Configure the Realname settings to use that new field (admin/config/people/realname) in my case the value was [user:field_display_name]
   [image: Configure Realname token setting]

After this the username was concealed from public display; Author display, User page alias & title and any views displaying author.

If you are using metatags module or some others you will need to configure them specifically to use the Realname value rather than the default username value, but it is a far more comprehensive way of solving the display name issue.